# Get Computer, assigned to particular User, via API in ServiceNow

Tags: api, servicenow

We have a User table with sys_id value and Computer table with value

```
assigned_to={  
  "link": "https://ourdomain.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/47d293bddber3d0d01b31a5ca0b961988",   
  "value": "47d293bddber3d0d01b31a5ca0b961988"    
}
```

I cannot just do "assigned_to = 47d293bddber3d0d01b31a5ca0b961988" as its an object
where "Value" is sys_id from User table.
So the question is - how do I find Computer assigned to particular user if I know User sys_id , with API?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you using the REST Table API, you can add the following parameter to your URL:

`&sysparm_query=assigned_to=47d293bddber3d0d01b31a5ca0b961988`

From the API perspective, **assigned_to** is not actually an object. It just a **sys_id**. ServiceNow adds the **link** to the JSON as a convenience. However, I usually find it to be **inconvenient**. I always get rid of it by adding the following parameter to my URL:

`&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true`

This will cause your JSON will return:

`"assigned_to": "47d293bddber3d0d01b31a5ca0b961988"`